# redis in Node does not wait for the return value and show Promise {<pending>}

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

```
const validateLoginInput = async (data) => {
  let errors = {};


  //check if user is blocked or not in redis cache
  await redisClient.select(2, (err) => {
    console.log('b');
    if (err) {
      console.log('c');
      errors.authFailedMessage = 'Server connection failed. Try again';
    } else {
      console.log('d');
      redisClient.get(`${data.userEmailLowerCase}`, (err, replay) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('e');
          errors.authFailedMessage = 'Server connection failed. Try again';
        } else if (replay === 'Blocked') {
          console.log('f');
          errors.authFailedMessage =
            'You are temporary blocked. Try again in an hour.';
        }
      });
    }
  });


  return {
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors),
  };
};

module.exports = validateLoginInput;
```

I am creating a list of blocked emails. I know that the problem is that the Promise returns the value too late before 'return' has been executed. However, I'd tried to use

```
new Promise(resolve, reject) or .then()
```

Both have not been working. .then() returns that redisClient() is not a function. And, I thought that async/await will wait for the promise to return. It seems working for other stuff but it doesn't work when I use it on redisClient.

Comment: You need to `await` the `redisClient.get` _instead_ of passing a callback: `const reply = await redisClient.get(data.userEmailLowerCase)`

Comment: how can I do that inside of the redisClient.select? I am trying to place async to make it works. But, I keep getting an error.

Comment: It shouldn't be _inside_ of the `select`. It should be `await redisClient.select(2);` and the rest afterwards. But, maybe your redis client library doesn't even support promises? Please show what library you use.

Comment: I am using  "redis": "^3.0.2"? I recently installed it.

Comment: The `redis` package doesn't natively support promises. You can either manually promisify the client [as suggested in their docs](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#promises) or use a different library like `ioredis` or `async-redis`. Check [this tutorial](https://thisdavej.com/guides/redis-node/node/intro.html) for a walkthrough with practical examples how to use `ioredis` with `async`/`await` in node.js.

Comment: Dang! I've been looking for if there were some packages for this. I will check out 'ioredis'. Thanks a lot!